# Server is running on 8080, but browser says webpage is unavailable

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost, server, port

I followed this tutorial (http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/node-js-server-side-javascript/) and when running the next to last script (for creating a static server) the command prompt says "Server running on port 8080", but when trying to access it at localhost:8080 I just get a webpage is unavailable error.

I have made an rule in the firewall to allow access to 8080 as well.

What could be causing this? Should i be trying to access the page from another address?

When I try to access the page i get the following error message in cmd:

```html
C:\Users\id122302\Documents\test.js:11
        path.exists(full_path,function(exists)
             ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\id122302\Documents\test.js:11:7)
    at Server.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:491:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:111:23)
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_server.js:343:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:538:20)
```

This is my code:

```html
var sys = require("sys");
my_http = require("http");
path = require("path");
url = require("url");
filesys = require("fs");
//Create Server
my_http.createServer(function(request,response)
{
 var my_path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
 var full_path = path.join(process.cwd(),my_path);
 path.exists(full_path,function(exists)
 {
  if (!exists)
  {
   response.writeHeader(404, {"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
   response.write("404 Not Found\n");
   response.end();
  }
  else
  {
   filesys.readFile(full_path, "binary", function(err,file)
   {
    if (err)
    {
     response.writeHeader(500,{"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
     response.write(err + "\n");
     response.end();
    }
    else
    {
     response.writeHeader(200);
     response.write(file,"binary");
     response.end();
    }
   });
  }
 });
}).listen(8080);
console.log("Server Running on 8080");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server shows an exception and a line number => go for that place !

As observed by @maniacnero, there's no more such thing as `path.exists` in the API. There's an `fs.exists` but it's been deprecated, to avoid abusive usage in node's concurrent context.

The feared scenario would be :

- you check asynchronously if a file exists.
- some other routine deletes/renames it in the meanwhile, or something else on the server does.
- you think that the file exists so you try to open it and confidently don't handle the error case.

So the lessons learnt here are :

- do things atomically
- always deal with failures right away

Provided you stick to this discipline, there's no need for such thing as `fs.exists`. Here's a modified version of your code :

```
var sys = require("sys");
var http = require("http");
var path = require("path");
var url = require("url");
var fs = require("fs");


var port = 8080;


http.createServer(function(request,response) {
    var my_path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    var full_path = path.join(process.cwd(),my_path);
    fs.readFile(full_path, function(err, file) {
        if (err) {
            response.writeHeader(404, {"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
            response.write("404 Not Found\n");
            response.end();
        } else {
            response.writeHeader(200);
            response.write(file);
            response.end();
        }
    });
}).listen(port);

console.log("Server Running on " + port);
```

I also removed those "binary" thingys, that are way outdated and not documented in the API either !

Playing around with sample code is a nice way to learn, but only if you don't do it blindly. ;) Especially in a weakly typed language building on a fast changing API and where myriads of tutorials have been written by utter beginners. This is your friend : https://nodejs.org/api/

Comment: thanks for the help and advice, running this code just gives me the 404, so now the challenge is just going to be to get the page to display, thank you for the help

Comment: put a test page on the same directory as the script ; say your test page is called "hi.txt" and contains "At laaaaaaast... :)" ; then call localhost:8080/hi.txt